# Hello World Angular2 app with typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am practising my first program in angular2 and I have some deviations from the expected output .

**typings.json:**

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#5c182b9af717f73146399c2485f70f1e2ac0ff2b"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-helloworld-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.7.12"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>My First Angular 2 App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside the app folder there are 2 files:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '<h1> Hello </h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {     
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';  
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

When I run the command, npm start the server is running without any errors but the output is:
**Loading...**

My expected output is :

```
'<h1> Hello </h1>'
```

whats it that I am missing?

Comment: You are seriously out of date. You are using Angular 2 packages from like a year ago. Upgrade! Upgrading will be extremely painful mind you, but if you do not, no one will be able to provide any support because things have changed radically.

Comment: @AluanHaddad : Please send me a proper reference study material with updated configuration. The above example is what I got finally.

Comment: Honestly, I would just start over at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html it doesn't sound like you have a lot of code. They introduced _many_, _many_ concepts, a massive amount of complexity, their own module system that exists alongside ES Modules, changed routing like 3 times, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution ,

in **app.component.ts** I have to use `template` instead of `templateUrl`